# For which $p>0$ does the following improper integral exist?

Tags: improper-integrals

The improper integral we have is $$\int^{1}_{0} |\ln{x}|^{p}dx$$ how do I approach this? I've never done anything like this and can't find any notes on it.

Thanks

Comment: do you need to know if it is finite or do you want to compute the integral?

Comment: If you set $u = \ln x$, i.e. $x = e^u$ then $dx = e^u du$ and you get $\int_{-\infty}^0 |u|^p e^u du$.

Comment: @Thorben as it says in the title, I want to know for which values of $p>0$ this integral exists. And FTP how does that help?

Comment: First I thought I can construct an integrable function wich bounds $|ln(x)|$ on $[0,1]$ to conclude that the integral must be finite. But i realised that the existence of such a bound is not so obvious...

Comment: This is Euler's first integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History).

Comment: @Lucian does it exist for all $p>0$?

Comment: It exists for all $p>-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $u=ln(x)$ to obtain,

$$\int_{-\infty}^0|u|^pe^udu$$

Then by integration by parts it follows,

$$\int_{-\infty}^0|u|^pe^udu=\int_{-\infty}^0(-u)^pe^udu=[(-u)^pe^u]_{-\infty}^0+p\int_{-\infty}^0(-u)^{p-1}e^udu$$
Repeat this $p$ times to get,

$$\int_{-\infty}^0|u|^pe^udu=p!$$

Comment: I understand what you've done so this clearly exists for every $p>0$ Right? Ps. There is no need for a substitution to get the same result

Comment: Yes it seems to hold for every $p$. I know, but in this case I prefer this way to compute the integral... It is just a matter of preferences :D

Answer (score 0):

Let $$I_p=\int_{0}^{1}|\log x|^p\mathrm{d}x.$$

Note that $$I_p=(-1)^p\int_{0}^{1}(\log x)^p\;\mathrm{d}x.$$
Start by $p=1$:

$$I_1=\int_{0}^{1}|\log x|^1\mathrm{d}x=-\int_{0}^{1}\log x\;\mathrm{d}x=-\left[x\log x-x\right]_{0}^{1}=-[-1-0]=1.$$
For $p=2$:

$$I_2=\int_{0}^{1}|\log x|^2\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}(\log x)^2\;\mathrm{d}x=\left[(\log x-1)x\log x\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}(\log x-1)\;\mathrm{d}x=\dotsc$$

Is this helps you?